# Duvidas - Captura de mensagens no Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Estou construindo um Teste no Selenium IDE (extensão chrome) para preencher um formulário e capturar a mensagem que o mesmo retorna em caso de erro.
No site, quando acontece um erro, a mensagem que eu gostaria de capturar é retornada dentro de um modal-dialog.

```
<h4 id="msgBody">Não foram encontradas contas habilitadas para pagamento. Tente pelo NIS.</h4>
```

A sequência construida no Selenium IDE é:
[image: Sequência deo Selenium]

Observei que existe uma opção de Assert Alert, porém ele não consegue capturar a contida no modal dialog.

Observações: Caso tenha duvidas do comportamento do sistema, o mesmo está disponível em:

https://fgts.caixa.gov.br/h6ul5o1obypimnfe1a05n59hyxwm8n2gkmrf2ju47bcjohnfiebx9a4xyqax/pages/inter/home.html

Dados gerados para teste:

CPF: 969.107.591-17
Data de Nascimento: 23/03/1956

Answer (score 1):

Cara tenta utilizar o seguinte xpath:

```
//div[@id="modalMsg"]//div[@class="modal-body"]//h4
```

Ele está encontrando a mensagem que você quer puxar.

caso não saiba utilizar o xpath no selenium IDE aqui está um exemplo: [Exemplo de como usar xPath](https://www.frontendtest.org/blog/selenium-ide-xpath-example/)